# Fetching text or image by there id from localhost mysql using volley

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-studio, android-volley

Description:

- I have stored some text and images (in url form) in a mysql database.
- Now I want to fetch that text in a particular text view, or images in
  a particular image view by there id using volley request method
- Also I want to use Glide to show that particular image in an assigned
  imageView.
- Below is the code I tried to fetch only text view but getting some problem,
  if anyone know how to fetch image also please help.

Java:

```java
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
try {  JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(response);
       JSONArray jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("name");
       JSONObject data = jsonarray.getJSONObject(0);
       String firstName = data.getString("pricewithfuel");

      textview.setText(firstName);
      } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
       }}},
new Response.ErrorListener() {
  @Override
  public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
}}){
  @Override
  protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
  Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
  params.put("id",editText.getText().toString());
    return params;
 }};
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mActivity);
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

PHP code

```php
 $connect=mysqli_connect($username,$hostname,$password,$dbname);

 $id = $_POST["id"];

 $query = "SELECT title FROM products WHERE id = '$id'";

 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
 $number_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

 $response = array();

 if($number_of_rows > 0) {
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         $response[] = $row;
     }
 }

 header('Content-Type: application/json');
 echo json_encode(array("users"=>$response));
 mysqli_close($connect);
```

Comment: Can you tell us specifically what problems you are getting.

Comment: **Warning** You're _wide open_ for [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) attacks. You should use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) with placeholders instead if using unescaped user data directly in your queries like that.

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching only title from the database,
Check your query again

```
SELECT title FROM products WHERE id = '$id'
```

Add more data fields from database which you wanted to display data